# Injecting service with injected service

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I don't understand why it's not injected properly. It throws this error:
Cannot read property 'productService' of undefined
at ProductValidator.validateCodeUnique (product-validator.ts:23)

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductValidator {

  constructor(public productService: ProductService) { }

  validateCodeUnique(input: FormControl) {
    const code: string = input.value;
    let isUnique = true;
    this.productService.getAllProducts().forEach((product, key) => {
      if (product.code === code) {
        isUnique = false;
      }
    });
    return isUnique ? null : { notValid: true };
  }
}
 validateCodeLength(input: FormControl) {
    const codeLength: number = input.value.length;
    const hasIncorrectLength = codeLength < 1 || codeLength > 10;
    return hasIncorrectLength ? null : { notValid: true };
  }
```

ProductService is also annotated as `Injectable`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
...
}
```

I declared both in module's providers:

```
providers: [ProductService, ProductValidator]
```

And I'm calling Validator from another modal window:

```
export class AddDialogComponent {
code = new FormControl('', [this.productValidator.validateCodeLength, this.productValidator.validateCodeUnique]);

constructor(public dataService: ProductService,
    public productValidator: ProductValidator)
...
}
```

`validateCodeLength` works fine, does someone has any idea why ProductService isn't injected? I'm injecting ProductService in another components where it works great. Have no idea what I'm missing here

Comment: You are trying to provide member function of a class to validator, But when validator function executes this or the context object changed... in order to avoid that you can achieve with higher order function or closure way

Comment: Replace `this.productValidator.validateCodeLength` by `this.productValidator.validateCodeLength.bind(this)` or by `control => this.productValidator.validateCodeLength(control)`. (Same for the other one, of course)

Comment: thank you guys, I got it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your error and you, actually, have to bind a context variable to your validation function every time you need to access it (i.e. the **this** variable).

I always did a `myValidationFunction.bind(this)` to those cases since the validation function was always declared in the same **Component** that the **FormControl** was being created but your case is an specific one.

In order to make your code run I had to:

```
this.productValidator.validateCodeUnique.bind(this.productValidator)
```

This is because you do not want the context variable **this** (inside the validation function) to be an instance of your **AddDialogComponent** where you create the **FormControl**, you actually want it to be a **ProductValidator** instance.

Hope it helps.