# Angular context binding

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I have problem probably with context function binding.

This is my AddDialogComponent which contains a FormGroup with code FormControl inside validated by injected ProductValidator:

```
constructor(
public productValidator: ProductValidator,
//.....
 code = new FormControl('', [
    this.productValidator.validateCodeLength.bind(this.productValidator),
    this.productValidator.validateCodeUnique.bind(this.productValidator)]);
```

ProductValidator's function:

```
 validateCodeUnique(input: FormControl) {
    const code: string = input.value;
    let isUnique = true;
    this.productService.getAllProducts().forEach((product, key) => {
      console.log(product);
      if (product.code === code) {
        isUnique = false;
      }
    });
    return isUnique ? null : { notUnique: true };
  }
```

And here `getAllProducts()` returns empty map but inside productService it shows 5 elements. fillMapProducts is called on initializing, the `console.log` printlns 5 items inside map, but later when I'm calling `getAllProducts()` in ProductValidator it shows that map is empty

```
fillMapProducts(products: ProductAdmin[]): ProductAdmin[] {
        products.forEach(product => this.allProducts.set(product.id, product));
    console.log(this.allProducts(); // 5 elements
      }

      getAllProducts(): Map<number, ProductAdmin> {
        return this.allProducts; // empty map when called inside ProductValidator
   }
```

I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977923/injecting-service-with-injected-service)  about that sometime ago and It worked very well - now I have no idea what should I do - I tried with some other bindings but didn't get expected results. Could someone help?

Comment: At what level is the service being provided?

Comment: It's provided in App Component